# Understanding a copy by reference of a dictionary property of a class

Tags: python, dictionary, reference, copy

Why is there a copy by reference at the line `new.dic2['a'] = i` in the following MWE, and their isn't at `new.dic1 = {'a':i}`?.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class a():
    dic1 = {'a':None}
    dic2 = {'a':None}

lst = []

print('creating list')
for i in range(2):
    new = a()
    new.dic1 = {'a':i}
    new.dic2['a'] = i

    print("lst[%d].dic1['a'] = %d" % (i,new.dic1['a']))
    print("lst[%d].dic2['a'] = %d" % (i,new.dic2['a']))
    lst.append(new)

print('showing list')
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print("lst[%d].dic1['a'] = %d" % (i,lst[i].dic1['a']))
    print("lst[%d].dic2['a'] = %d" % (i,lst[i].dic2['a']))
```

This prints

creating list:

```
lst[0].dic1['a'] = 0
lst[0].dic2['a'] = 0
lst[1].dic1['a'] = 1
lst[1].dic2['a'] = 1
```

showing list:

```
lst[0].dic1['a'] = 0
lst[0].dic2['a'] = 1
lst[1].dic1['a'] = 1
lst[1].dic2['a'] = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new instance with `new = a()`, initially the `new` instance does not contain either `dic1` or `dic2`, but inherits them through the class.  But when you make the following assignment:

```
new.dic1 = {'a':i}
```

This creates an instance variable for `dic1` in the instance `new`.  So at this point, `new` contains a single instance variable, `dic1`, but still picks up `dic2` from the class.

If you then make changes to `new.dic1`, they are local to `new` since it has its own copy of `dic1`.  But if you make changes to `new.dic2`, it changes the class variable `a.dic2`.

The second time through the loop, a new class instance is created, and after the assignment to `new.dic1` it too has its own instance of `new.dic1`, but `new.dic2` in both of the instances refer back to `a.dic2` when accessed.  So changes to `dic2` are reflected in both instances, and in the class itself, while changes to `dic1` are local to each instance.